# Using basename()

Tags: php, html

We have a program that exports an image as .bmp and creates an associated .txt file. Each file is generated incrementally  so that the first file set is named 0.bmp and 0.txt, second 1.bmp and 1.txt, etc. I have the following

```
    <?php 
    $dir = "Photos/Marshfield/*";
    foreach(glob($dir) as $sub)    
    {
        $path = $sub."/*";
        foreach(glob($path) as $file)
        {
            echo "<img src=".$file.">";
        }
    }       
    ?>
```

To further add to the trouble shooting when you echo $base you get the following: `0.bmp0.txt1.bmp1.txt2.bmp2.txt3.bmp3.txt4.bmp4.txt5.bmp5.txt6`, it sees the file as those two parts. I'll be honest it took me most of today to learn php to the point where I was able to put the above together. Not knowing the language very well can someone provide some guidance on how I can ensure that the appropriate image/text association per each directory is correct? I think if I could break the two apart I might be able to work further but I'm not sure on the best approach.

In the directory specified "Photos/Marshfield" there are a series of directories (Lets say D1, D2, D3, etc) within each of those directories are a listing of files each having a 0.bmp/0.txt, 1.bmp/1.txt, etc combo. What I would like to do is loop through all directories and within each sub-directory (the D1, D2, etc) match up and display the image file and the corresponding text file. Initially I had hoped that joining $dic and $base I could call the source for the image since they are numerically incremented. $dic would produce "Photos/Marshfield/D1 and using the base name of my .bmp file I should get a number which when added back to .bmp completes the file path. What I had expected from basename() was to return the string value of the file (in this case 0, 1, 2, etc) instead it returns 0.bmp0.txt as the file, I hope that helps clarify. I had not gotten around to producing the contents of reading the text file although I have that part down.

I updated my code to loop through all directories and sub-directories labeled as * in the path $dir. That part is complete now just tying the contents of the appropriate text file in.

Comment: So what is the actual problem you are having? What is it you expect to be doing with this `${$dic.$base}`?

Comment: You should utilize `glob("*/*.bmp")` to only get one kind of files. Also `intval()` would suffice here inplace of `basename()`. What you probably meant for output is `echo "<img src=$dic/$base.bmp> ";`.

Comment: I think he's joining two variables to create a new name.

Comment: 1. You added the local path parts to the img tag. Probably you should use a server relative path.
2. you can use the glob like $dir='.....bmp'; In this way the file name creation can be much simpler.
3. I don't either understand the ${$dic.$base} path...

Comment: ${} converts anything inside the curly brackets into a var. So if $a =1; and $b = 2; then $c = {$a.$b} = $12;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem that `glob()` only looks in the current directory. Since you only want the `.bmp` files your code should look more like:

```
<?php
foreach(glob('*.bmp') as $file){
  $base = file_get_contents(basename('$file', '.bmp').'.txt');
  echo "<img src='$file' /><div>$base</div>";
}
?>
```

Personally, I like to keep my PHP somewhat separate from HTML, so I would actually do this, if you want all the results together:

```
<?php
$out = ''
foreach(glob('*.bmp') as $file){
  $base = file_get_contents(basename('$file', '.bmp').'.txt');
  $out .= "<img src='$file' /><div>$base</div>";
}
echo $out; // anywhere you want
?>
```

If you want to put each result anywhere, then:

```
<?php
foreach(glob('*.bmp') as $file){
  $base = file_get_contents(basename('$file', '.bmp').'.txt');
  $img[] = "<img src='$file' />";
  $div[] = "<div>$base</div>";
}
echo "<div id='someId'>$img[3]</div>";
?>
```

Now you can access `$div[0]` or whatever and stick it right between double quote surrounded HTML. Just make sure if you have an Associative Array Element, to surround it with `{}`, like:

```
echo "div id='someId'>{$img['ArrayKeyHere']}</div>";
```

You tried to access a variable variable *(look it up)*, forgot quotes, and more. Brace yourself, while learning. It may be a rough ride.

Hopefully this was somewhat Educational.

If this does not serve your purpose, look into `readdir()`. You will have to use a loop to filter out the files you don't want. Note that we are not here to do your work for you, just teach you how to do it.

Comment: I would agree this does return the image files I want but I need to ensure that the image file is associated with the correct text file created with it.

Comment: Since the scope of glob is the local directory and I specified out Photos/Marshfield/*/* two directories past where I need to loop through do you think it might be better to start in Photos/Marshfield/* and do a nested foreach loop to go through all of the directories at the *?

Comment: You can't `glob()` a directory you are not in, therefore a loop over a loop of subdirectories will do no good.

Comment: I made edits to my initial to indicate what I was talking about, using glob() to loop through my sub-directories. You gave me the idea : )

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong for GLOB. I think it requires a directory path and the pattern for filematch. I think leaving it empty might return all files.

Okay... I get your question. Now that you've added some more details. 
What you want to do is iterate over all the images (or text files in the directory), and then check to see if the image & text file exist.

```
 <?php 
 $absPath = 'ABSOLUTE PATH TO YOUR FILES';
 $dir = $absPath . "Photos/Marshfield/";
 $matches = glob($dir."*.bmp");

 if(is_array($matches)) {
    $txtFile = '';
    foreach(glob($dir.'*.bmp') as $key=>$file ) {

      //Creates the base name without the extension
      $base = basename($file,".bmp");

      $txtFile = $base . $key .'.txt <br />';
      if(file_exists($txtFile)) {
         //File and Img
         echo $txtFile .'<br />';
         echo '<img src="'.$absPath . $dir. $base . $key . '.bmp" >';
      } else {
         echo 'No text file found';
         echo '<img src="'.$absPath . $dir. $base . $key . '.bmp" >';
      }

    }  
 }     
 ?>
```

Comment: In this case I'm calling my site in the same directory has Photos which I believe would make this the absolute path thus I guess I don't see the need for $absPath.

Comment: $absPath is optional, but I find it helps when you're on a remote server and you have a URL rewrites, or pretty URLs and the like on more complex sites.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) together with [`FilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/filteriterator) here:

```
class FileFilterIterator extends FilterIterator 
{
    public function accept()
    {
        $file = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();

        return ($file->getExtension() == 'bmp') && file_exists(
            "{$file->getPath()}/{$file->getBasename('bmp')}txt");
    }
}

foreach (new FileFilterIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('Photos/Marshfield'))) as $file) {
    printf('<img src="%s" />', $file->getPathname());
    printf('Text file: %s', "{$file->getPath()}/{$file->getBasename('bmp')}txt");
}
```

PS: I've added `file_exists()` checking per your comment *"I need to ensure that the image file is associated with the correct text file created with it"*.

Comment: My apologies but I'm not yet apt enough yet to fully understand the structure of what you are doing. I do not what to use something that I fully don't understand.

Comment: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` iterates all directory files recursively like `glob()` does with `*` pattern. `RecursiveIteratorIterator` iterates the prior recursive iterator. `FileFilterIterator` is a class we've just created that extends `FilterIterator` which implements an `accept()` method that will filter all files based on your own conditions (in this case all filenames with "bmp" extension which have same basename file with "txt" extension). Then `foreach` iterates all matched files and give you methods to get pathname, filename, etc. :)